# Is it possible to sample audio using MTAudioProcessingTap with Xamarin?

Tags: c#, ios, audio, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have created the below solution in an attempt to sample a small mp4 file (included in the solution) using MTAudioProcessingTap however, the application crashes moments after starting without throwing any exception or generating output.

https://github.com/afalz/AudioProcessing

Through debugging I can see the process delegate is being called and data is getting into the bufferList via the getSourceAudio call however, once I let execution continue - the app crashes.

Has anyone else tried using this particular class with Xamarin and been successful?